# Merging two json in PHP

Tags: php, json, merge

I have two json's

First one is

```
    [{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Order Number"}
,{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Customer Number"}]
```

Second one is

```
[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUE":"1521"},
{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUEE":"C1435"}]
```

I want to merge them and have a json like

```
[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Order Number","DEFAULT_VALUE":"1521"}
,{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Customer Number","DEFAULT_VALUEE":"C1435"}]
```

is there a way to merge them? It is also OK for me if a stucture change in JSON is required

thanks.

Comment: 1 Convert them to php data structures 2 Merge them 3 Convert back to json

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
json_encode(
    array_merge(
        json_decode($a, true),
        json_decode($b, true)
    )
)
```

or the same as one-liner:

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true)))
```

**[array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)** in official PHP documentation

**[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** in official PHP documentation

*EDIT:* try adding `true` as second parameter to json_decode. That'll convert objects to associative arrays.

*EDIT 2*: try `array-merge-recursive` and see my comment below. Sorry have to log out now :(
This looks like a full correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286594/1466341

Comment: thank you for the answer but the result is [{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Order Number"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Customer Number"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUE":"1521"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUE":"C1435"}] it is adding the second json after the first one.  isn't it possible only to have the missing key and value added to the first one.. Please see my expected result

Comment: see my edit above. That should be closer to what you need, but I guess that will return objects as encoded arrays in JSON as result (sorry, no time to test that now) :(

Comment: It didn't change the result. Again it is adding the array after the previous one

Comment: Ah I see now. You have to merge elements recursively like with this function http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php, but catch here is that when you have numeric keys in array, then it'll not merge sub-elements. Brutal solution would be to first decode all jsons, then merge their sub-elements in loop one by one and then encode result in json. Sorry, have to log out now :(

Comment: Like I said - this looks like a correct solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286594/1466341

Answer (score 10):

Managed to throw this together. There is most likely a better solution, but this is the closest I got.

```
$a = '[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Order Number"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","COLUMN_TITLE":"Customer Number"}]';
$b = '[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUE":"1521"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUEE":"C1435"}]';
$r = [];
foreach(json_decode($a, true) as $key => $array){
 $r[$key] = array_merge(json_decode($b, true)[$key],$array);
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

returns,

```
[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ORDER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUE":"1521","COLUMN_TITLE":"Order Number"},
{"COLUMN_NAME":"CUSTOMER_NO","DEFAULT_VALUEE":"C1435","COLUMN_TITLE":"Customer Number"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

This works like a charm for me

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true)))
```

here is a full example

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `customer` where patient_id='1111118'";

$mysql_result = mysql_query($query);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$json_personal_information=json_encode($rows);
//echo $json_personal_information;




$query="SELECT * FROM `doctor` where patient_id='1111118'";

$mysql_result = mysql_query($query);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$json_doctor_information=json_encode($rows);
//echo $json_doctor_information;

echo $merger=json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($json_personal_information, true),json_decode($json_doctor_information, true)));
```

Comment: I must be missing something. Won't the 2nd encode write over the first one?

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook because after each while loop, the result of $rows is stored to a different variable ($json_personal_information and $json_doctor_information). These two variables are used in the array_merge.

Answer (score 1):

This worked to me!

```php
$dados1 = json_encode(array('data'=>'1')); 
$dados2 = json_encode(array('data2'=>'2')); 
echo json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($dados1, true),json_decode($dados2, true)));
```