# Merge two 2 Dimensional json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have two Two Dimensional json.

```
[{"4":"213231.jpg"},{"5":"Cadbury 5 star Chocolate.jpg"}]

[{"1":"slider-1.png"},{"2":"slider-2.png"},{"3":"slider-3.png"},{"4":"slider-4.png"},{"5":"slider-5.png"}]
```

i want to merge this two arrays and i want the answer as

```
[{"1":"slider-1.png"},{"2":"slider-2.png"},{"3":"slider-3.png"},{"4":"213231.jpg"},{"5":"Cadbury 5 star Chocolate.jpg"}]
```

Comment: What is the problem and what does your first array look like exactly?

Comment: i dont know how to merge it?

Comment: You are not merging anything, your output is the same as your second array of your input.

Comment: now i correct it please take a look..

Comment: Refer this link might help you 
  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php

Comment: In both json ,You have "5",which "5" you want in merged json ,don't you want both values of it? because in your merged json you took first value ,Is that only value you want?

Comment: yes that only i want..

Comment: There is no such thing as merging `JSON`s. `JSON` is just an encoding of some data structure. Use `json_decode('...', TRUE)` to restore the data as arrays and use of (or more) of the many PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to get the data structure you want. Also, if you display the decoded data structures (using `print_r()` or `var_export()`) everything becomes more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
$json1 = '[{"1":"slider-1.png"},{"2":"slider-2.png"},{"3":"slider-3.png"},{"4":"slider-4.png"},{"5":"slider-5.png"}]';
$json2 = '[{"4":"213231.jpg"},{"5":"Cadbury 5 star Chocolate.jpg"}]';

echo json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($json1), json_decode($json2)));
```

**Output**

> [{"1":"slider-1.png"},{"2":"slider-2.png"},{"3":"slider-3.png"},{"4":"slider-4.png"},{"5":"slider-5.png"},{"4":"213231.jpg"},{"5":"Cadbury
>   5 star Chocolate.jpg"}]

Comment: but i dont want `{"4":"slider-4.png"},{"5":"slider-5.png"}]` this to come?

Comment: Updated answer with reverse placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$json1 = '[{"1":"slider-1.png"},{"2":"slider-2.png"},{"3":"slider-3.png"},{"4":"slider-4.png"},{"5":"slider-5.png"}]';
$json2 = '[{"4":"213231.jpg"},{"5":"Cadbury 5 star Chocolate.jpg"}]';

$json1 = json_decode($json1);
unset($json1[4],$json1[5]);
$json1 = json_encode($json1);
echo json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($json1), json_decode($json2)));
```

Comment: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` error.

Comment: Thanks For Your Help.. But I tried With Different Concept. Thank You