# Aggregating JSON output

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON output on PHP like:

```
[{"Title":"Message","count":"180","Number":"200"},
 {"Title":"Message","count":"200","Number":"400"}]
```

How can I obtain a result like the following?

```
[{"Title":"Message","count":"380","Number":"600"}]
```

Comment: How to implement it in php code please??i am a begining programmer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two json in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php/20286594#20286594)

Answer (score 0):

In php:

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true)))
```

Refer : [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286594/2142994)

Comment: Thank you for your repons but it return still duplicate value, I would like grouping by "Message" and make sum to "count" and "number"