# Combining multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json file that runs as follows

```
{
"1" : [...],
"2" : [...]
}
```

Is there any way to combine them all as one?

Comment: Question is unclear.  what expected outcome you want? and what code you have tried so for?

Comment: `json_decode()` and `array_merge()`? What have you tried? Expected result?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php

Comment: There's just one object there. What do you want to combine it with?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a javascript code for this.

```
    var primarJson = {

    "1" : [1, 2,3,4],
    "2" : [5, 6,7,8],
    "3" : [9, 10,11,12],
    "4" : [13, 14,15,16]
}
var combinedJson = { "final" : []}
for(var i in primarJson){

    combinedJson.final = combinedJson.final.concat(primarJson[i]);

}
```

Comment: The question is tagged PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: oh! My bad for php you can use array_merge for each of the json array object and push them in a fresh array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$primarJson = '{

    "1" : [1, 2,3,4],
    "2" : [5, 6,7,8],
    "3" : [9, 10,11,12],
    "4" : [13, 14,15,16]
}';

$finalArray = json_decode('{"final" : []}', true);


foreach (json_decode($primarJson) as $key => $value) {
    $finalArray['final'] = array_merge($value, $finalArray['final']);
}


print_r(json_encode($finalArray));
```

?>