# How to append to json_encode array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, string

i have a validation checker that checks the database to see if the "email and username" is being used and if so then echo the email and username as "false". And if its not in the database then echo to "true". I am returning the results of the users email and username being in the sql sever. So i want to append "$json1 or $json2" to the "$first or $second" like this

```
 {"Email":false, "Username":true};
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    //Connect to database
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "magicsever");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()){

        die ("Database connection error");
    }

    //Find the email in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['email'])."'";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['username'])."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);

    $email_checker1 = json_encode(array("Email"=>false));
    $email_checker2 = json_encode(array("Email"=>true));

    $username_checker1 = json_encode(array("Username"=>false));
    $username_checker2 = json_encode(array("Username"=>true));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

        echo $email_checker1;


    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make new array for email and username results

```
//Find the email in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['email'])."'";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['username'])."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);

$dataResult = array();
$dataResult['Email'] = (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)? false: true;
$dataResult['Username'] = (mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0)? false: true;

echo json_encode($dataResult );
```

Comment: I got an error on the $dataResult = new array(); line.

Comment: or just use `$dataResult = [];`

Comment: or just remove the new in array. sorry. wrong syntax

Comment: D: i am returning the results of the users email and username being in the sql sever. So the set booleans wont be the result

Comment: but what if  there's no result?

Comment: There will be because, if the email is in the database then i return "Email: false" and if its not there then i return "Email: true". And now i want to append this result to the username second where if its there i return "Username: false" etc.

Comment: `{"Email":false, "Username":true};` this is what you want right? or `{"Email":"SampleEmail", "Username":"SampleUsername"};` this?

Comment: {"Email":false, "Username":true}; because it will return the true and false which the app creator can read and tell the user if the username or email is taken or not.

Comment: then my answer is correct. `(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)? false: true` it will return false if the result is greater than 0 rows, else true.

Comment: OHH i do apologize then, can you please, if you can, go into more detail about each line of code you beginning with $dataResult. Sorry i am new to this backend stuff :D

Comment: So what you did was set an empty array for the results then you said "if the email is in the rows set it to false OR true" and if "username is in he rows set to false or true" then print the results and it will put it in the same curly brackets?

Comment: yes. `(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)? false: true;` this one is called ternary operators (?:)  `(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)? 'indicate return value here if true' : 'else false';`

Comment: oh but how did it know i wanted the result structured like i have there. Is it the ternary operators that automatically put it in the json format?

Comment: no. this code `json_encode($dataResult );` is used to set your array in a json format. that ternary operator is an if else statement

Answer (score 0):

JSON is only a data format, a way to present a data structure. Until you have a data structure that is ready to be presented, you don't want to convert it to JSON.

What you should do is to build an array containing the validation errors:

```
// I'm assuming that the true/false means that there was an error with validating that value
// You can initialize the validation array with false values for all fields and change them to true in case of validation error
$errors = ['Email' => false, 'Username' => false];

// Then, change the values in case of an error
if (... /* invalid email */) {
    $errors[] = ['Email' => true];
}
if (... /* invalid username */) {
    $errors[] = ['Username' => true];
}
```

Then convert the array to JSON only when you display it:

```
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Comment: The true means "the email and username that was inputted is available to take" and false means " its has already been taken"

Comment: That doesn't change my answer in any way. But perhaps you'd like to write your code in a descriptive way, so that you don't have to explain what you just did with an extra comment. How about naming the keys in the array `email_available` and `username_available`?

Comment: i see what you do, but i want them in the same curly brackets not like separated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do json_encode after the array append.

```
$first = json_encode(array("Email"=>false, "Username"=>false));
```

added.

```
$data['Email'] = false;
if('''')
{
  $data['Username'] = false;
}
$result = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This would work if the username was true and email is false. I dont want a simply echo where i type it, i want to append if either or happens.

Comment: So you created a data varible and passed "email" to it and you set it to false? but the problem is i am returning the results of the users email and username being in the sql sever.

Comment: You just store the json string to your sql server, it have no difference which variable store this value.

Comment: its not being stored in the sql server. I am taking it info from the server then sending the json file to an app that reads the information and displays something to the user. Sorry if i seem "dumb" in programming D: i am still learning

Comment: $variable just store the value, what the variable name is have no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $first = json_encode(array("Email"=>false));
    $second = json_encode(array("Email"=>true));

    $json1 = json_encode(array("Username"=>false));
    $json2 = json_encode(array("Username"=>true));
```

use like this

```
$first = json_encode(array("Email"=>false)+array("Username"=>true));
$second = json_encode(array("Email"=>true)+array("Username"=>false));
```

Comment: Close the way i structure the code is i check if the email is taken first and if it is, then check if the username is taken and then from the username side i append the message from username to the email in the first if statement.  So your way kinda works

Answer (score 0):

If you really want merge them together go through this references

- [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php/20286594#20286594)
- [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php)

Good approach would be like

```
$resData1['email']=false;
$resData2['email']=true;

$resData1['Username']=false;
$resData2['Username']=true;

$json1 = json_encode($resData1);
$json2 = json_encode($resData2);
```

Comment: Hmm the problem with that is i am getting the same result "false and false" or "true and true" back. Is it possible to change like append he false and true with different variable names?

Comment: because the code is written like that.... you might need to use an if condition..like if email return as false set to false or give true. Something like that will works

Comment: Yea i thought of that but i would have to create and if statement for different scenarios and i am trying to find a less crazier way of doing it.