# Merge and transpose the data from two json strings containing flat array structures

Tags: php, arrays, json, transpose, merging-data

I have two JSONs which both have the same keys and I want to merge them based on their related keys.

My first json: `{"3":"test","4":"exam"}`

My second json: `{"3":"12","4":"19"}`

I want to have an array like this:

```
array("final") {
 [3]=> {
   "name" => "test"
   "quantity" => "12"
  } 
  [4]=> {
   "name" => "exam"
   "quantity" => "19"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two json in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the json objects to array

```
 $x = json_decode($x);
 $y = json_Decode($y);
 $res['final'] = [];
 foreach($x as $key => $value)
 {
  foreach($y as $k => $v)
  {
    if($key == $k)
    {
        $res['final'][$key]['name'] = $value;
        $res['final'][$key]['quantity'] = $v;
    }
  }
 }
 print_r($res);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
[final] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => test
                [quantity] => 12
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => exam
                [quantity] => 19
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **json_decode** and **array_merge**

First json_decode your first and second json

```
$firstJson = json_decode(jsonData); 
$secondJson = json_decode(jsonData);
```

And merge them using array_merge

```
array_merge($first_json, $secondJson);
```