# Merging 2 json files where not all data matches up

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have 2 json files that I need to merge together, but the situation is somewhat unique.

So lets call the first movies.json:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
]
```

And lets call the second movies2.json

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1"
    }
        {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "description": "description of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie3"
    }
]
```

I need to merge these two files in such a way that there are no duplicates while considering filters may not exist in one file or the other.

Thus my desired output from the 2 examples would look like

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "description": "description of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie3"
    }
]
```

What I currently have looks like the following

```
<?php
    $arr1 = file_get_contents('movies.json');
    $arr2 = json_decode($arr1, true);

    $arr3 = file_get_contents('movies2.json');
    $arr4 = json_decode($arr3, true);

    $arr5 = array_unique(array_merge($arr2, $arr4), SORT_REGULAR);

    $arr = json_encode($arr5, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents('movies3.json', $arr);
```

The result of this is:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1"
    }
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "description": "description of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie3"
    }
]
```

As we can see the result is not desired. Although it removed the duplicate "movie 2" it considered each "movie 1" unique... I assume because one has the "filters" key and the other does not.

How can I merge these two files in such a way that I will get desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two json in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php)

Comment: @OMiShah no the solutions on that page produce the exact same results listed on this page. They end up with duplicates.

Comment: Could you specify when an entry is a duplicate? This is not self-evident. Are they the same when the titles are the same? What if the URL differs? Can the URL's differ for the same title? Or the description? So, how do we decide something is the same film, and what to do with any differences between these entries?

Comment: If the titles are the same one is duplicate. If one contains a `filters` key , that is the one to keep.

Answer (score 0):

We merge in the loop we need to loop around to reach each array and merge it with it's parallel other - I have changed the json a bit to illustrate the merge better:

```
<?php

$movies1 = '[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
]';

$movies2 =  '[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1"
    },
        {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "description": "description of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie3"
    }
]';


$movies1A = json_decode($movies1,true);
$movies2A = json_decode($movies2,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($movies1A);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($movies2A);
$newM = [];
foreach ($movies1A as $key => $m1){

    foreach($movies2A as $ky => $m2){
            $newM = array_merge($m1,$m2);
            $movies2A[$key] = $newM;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($movies2A);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 1
            [description] => description of Movie 1
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie1
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 2
            [description] => description of Movie 2
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie2
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 3
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie2
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 1
            [description] => description of Movie 1
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 2
            [description] => description of Movie 2
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie2
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 3
            [description] => description of Movie 3
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 3
            [description] => description of Movie 3
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie3
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 3
            [description] => description of Movie 3
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie3
            [filters] => list, of, filters
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of Movie 3
            [link] => CDN_url_to_movie3
            [filters] => list, of, filters
            [description] => description of Movie 3
        )

)
```

Notice I have added on purpose title 3 in both with a difference to show how it merges! :)

just $movies2A = json_encode($movies2A); at the end and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the `title` attribute is unique for each array, you can use the `array_column` function to make it the key of the associative array, and then merge it through the `array_replace_recursive` function.

```
$arr1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$result = array_values(array_replace_recursive(
    array_column($arr1, null, 'title'),
    array_column($arr2, null, 'title')
));
```

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5929105eb2f2a3ed0e3c817628106a93ba0f520)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit harder to do than it, at first, seems. I've written some very explicit code, where it is easy to understand what it does, and that this is a correct solution.

Basically I detect all duplicates, keep only the correct ones in another array, while deleting all of them from the original arrays. Then I merge the original arrays and stored correct duplicates.

I do not sort the result. And this will only work if the original arrays do not contain duplicates themselves.

```
<?php

// it is obvious what this starts with, so I left that out
$movies1 = json_decode($moviesJson1);
$movies2 = json_decode($moviesJson2);

// first we find the duplicated movies, and choose the one with filters
$duplicates = [];
$removeKeys1 = [];
$removeKeys2 = [];
foreach ($movies1 as $key1 => $movie1) {
    foreach ($movies2 as $key2 => $movie2) {
        if ($movie1->title == $movie2->title) {
            $duplicates[] = property_exists($movie1, "filters") ? $movie1 : $movie2;
            $removeKeys1[] = $key1;
            $removeKeys2[] = $key2;
        }
    }    
}

// then we remove all duplicated movies from the original arrays
foreach ($removeKeys1 as $key) {
    unset($movies1[$key]);
}
foreach ($removeKeys2 as $key) {
    unset($movies2[$key]);
}

// finally we merge everything that's left
$movies = array_merge($movies1, $movies2, $duplicates);
$moviesJson = json_encode($movies, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $moviesJson;
```

This returns:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 3",
        "description": "description of Movie 3",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 1",
        "description": "description of Movie 1",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie1",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title of Movie 2",
        "description": "description of Movie 2",
        "link": "CDN_url_to_movie2",
        "filters": "list, of, filters"
    }
]
```

Here is [the working demo code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff58eeee33083162f2427e05ef47822063df8af6)

As said, this code was not written to present the most clever solution, but just code that actually works. However, because I can, I added a version without the key arrays:

```
$movies1 = json_decode($moviesJson1);
$movies2 = json_decode($moviesJson2);

// first we find the duplicated movies, and choose the one with filters
$duplicates = [];
foreach ($movies1 as $key1 => $movie1) {
    foreach ($movies2 as $key2 => $movie2) {
        if ($movie1->title == $movie2->title) {
            $duplicates[] = property_exists($movie1, "filters") ? $movie1 : $movie2;
        }
    }    
}

// then we remove all duplicated movies from the original arrays by title
$duploTitles = array_column($duplicates, "title");
foreach (["movies1", "movies2"] as $arrayName) {
    foreach (array_column(${$arrayName}, "title") as $key => $title) {
        if (in_array($title, $duploTitles)) {
            unset(${$arrayName}[$key]);
        }    
    }
}

// finally we merge everything that's left
$movies = array_merge($movies1, $movies2, $duplicates);
$moviesJson = json_encode($movies, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here is [the working demo code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39a737818376259d614aab3f0f444d3ff01dffa4)

This does exactly the same thing. You could call this code a bit smarter, but, to be honest, it is probably slightly slower, and definitely harder to understand. I would use the first solution.